# Django on IIS WinServer 2012R2 with python 3.9 WSGI Handler error

Tags: python, django, iis

I'm trying to setup an IIS website following this [guide](https://luthebao.com/2021/02/python-django-how-to-deploy-one-or-many.html)

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", 
line 791, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) 

File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", 
line 633, in read_wsgi_handler handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER")) 

File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", 
line 586, in get_wsgi_handler raise Exception('WSGI_HANDLER env var must be set') 

Exception: WSGI_HANDLER env var must be set 
StdOut: StdErr:
```

I believe the error might be on the web.config, which is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Python FastCGI"
                path="*"
                verb="*"
                modules="FastCgiModule"
                scriptProcessor="C:\Python39\python.exe|C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
                resourceType="Unspecified"
                requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
<appSettings>
        <!-- Required settings -->
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django_project.wsgi.application" />
        <!-- Your django path -->
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\django_project" /> 
        <!-- Your djangoname.settings -->
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="django_project.settings" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

my folder structure is the following:

> C:\Python39\python.exe
> C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

**C:\django_project** that has the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

and I have created the FastCGI settings with:
[image]

and Handler Mapping with: (the request restriction has the invoce box unticked)
[image]

I don't know what else could I be missing to set here.

Comment: Check the folder `C:\Python39` permissions in Explorer. Does your app pool user (`IIS AppPool\NAME_OF_YOUR_APPPOOL`) have access?

Comment: yes, it does have permit, the app pool, and the IUSRS and IUSRS users

Comment: Please check whether the environment variables in the FastCGI handler settings are correct.